# Google Maps - Server-side Clustering

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, cluster-analysis

I've got about 500 000 markers and naturally I cannot display them all. I've tried [MakerClusterer](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclusterer/1.0/examples/advanced_example.html) but it was too complex for js to plot clusters on map. I was thinking on [server-side clusterer](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/php_google_maps/cluster.html) but it was much slower than javascript solution!!!

Do you know any solution of this problem? I know that 500 000 is very huge number but php should be at least as fast as js. That's probably a matter of implementation. Perhaps there is some other solution like this that is known to be efficient?

Thanks

Comment: You may have optimization potential in your server side app. It's impossible to tell without knowing details though

Comment: Yes, you're right. The problem is that the php script runs more than one hour without any result. Javascript version needs about 10 mins. It must be bad coding style or something.

Comment: Could maybe just be a bug in your code? An infinite loop, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also have a look at using Fusion Tables http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#FusionTables

Comment: Looks interesting: http://googlemapsmania.blogspot.com/2010/05/fusion-tables-google-maps-api.html.

Comment: But Fusion-Tables isn't clustering!

Comment: Please expand on this answer beyond a link. Why would it help?

Comment: @Tim: If you mean this http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-fusiontables-simple.html then it is not clustering because you see every marker not nested with the zoom-level. IMO a server-side clustering is when you have some sort of spatial index and run a BFS against it. See also my post about a sfc and quadtrees.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look for a space-filling-curve or a spatial index (database). A sfc reduce the 2d complexity to a 1d complexity. You want to look for Nick's hilbert curve quadtree spatial index blog. BTW. I've implemented a php class to use a hilbert curve to search for postcodes. It's using a table non-recursive approach and can use all 4 hilbert-curves. You can find my class at phpclasses.org (hilbert-curve).

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind using Django, you can try my app:

https://github.com/biodiv/anycluster

It uses postgis kmeans clustering. You can easily adapt the mechanisms to your map e.g. by choosing between gridcluster/kmeanscluster depending on zoom level for optimizing the performance.